# How to access the event when a list of radio button is selected at a context menu strip?

Tags: c#, radio-button, windows-forms-designer, contextmenustrip, toolstripcontrolhost

I'm creating the radio buttons in the *ContextMenuStrip* using the *ToolStripControlHost*, this way

```
RadioButton taskRb = new RadioButton();
taskRb.Text = DataGridTable.getTasks()[i].name.ToString();
taskRb.Checked = false;
ToolStripControlHost tRb = new ToolStripControlHost(taskRb);
contextMenuStrip2.Items.Add(tRb);
```

I need an event like *CheckedChanged* for the radio buttons in this list, so I can perform some actions when one of the buttons is checked.

What is the best way to do this? since I can't use this event with the *ToolStripControlHost*.

Comment: Can you register an event handler on the RadioButton?

Comment: Posted it as an answer if you want to accept it :)

Comment: Marked. Sorry for the delay :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register an event handler for the `CheckedChanged` event of the `RadioButton`:

```
RadioButton taskRb = new RadioButton();

taskRb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(taskRb_CheckedChanged);
taskRb.Text = DataGridTable.getTasks()[i].name.ToString();
taskRb.Checked = false;

ToolStripControlHost tRb = new ToolStripControlHost(taskRb);
contextMenuStrip2.Items.Add(tRb);

protected void taskRb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```